# Most space efficient way to store 200 million records?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I have this type of record:

1. **name**        varchar(128)
2. **description** varchar(64)
3. **field**       varchar(32)

Combination of (name, description) needs to be unique and  **name** needs to be indexed for fast search/retrieval.  Updates are infrequent, but large for example I might add 1 million records at a time, but there plenty of reads throughout the day.

I have over 200 million records like these, possibly becoming 300 in the future, when I tried adding it to MySQL, DB has grown huge I'm looking at 200GB+ with all the indices and etc.  Is there a space efficient way to  structure this data.  Any DB tech is fine with me, as long it does not need lots of ram and uses less disk.

200 million * (128+64+32) = ~50GB of data. Don't know how MySQL stores data, but I'm guessing it creates an index for unique key(124+64), so already we are talking about **50GB + ~index 40Gb** of data.  There is some other overhead, possibly due to fragmentation as suggested below.

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Are your indexes fragmented? That sounds like alot of space for a fresh table of 200 millions rows

Comment: 200 million * (128+64+32) = 50GB of data.  Don't know how MySQL stores data, but I'm guessing it creates an index for unique key(124+64), so already we are talking about 50GB + index 40Gb of data.  I assume the index is fragmented, which adds more space.   I'm trying to lower the storage cost, as the bigger the files the more it costs me for server space, and replication and backups.

Comment: 90GB is not so big. If you have concerns about Disk size, try tokuDB or use Compressed format of InnoDB.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to store non-relational information in a relational database? What types of queries are you doing on this data?

Comment: I'm open to other DBs.  99% of the queries do very simple lookups. As long as it can handle simultaneous lookups from multiple processes.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-physical-record.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both MySQL and SQLite store text values in dynamically-sized records; table or index entries are *not* padded.

You can avoid the space needed for the index for the UNIQUE constraint by making the name/description columns the primary key and thus using a clustered index ([requires InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) in MySQL, or [WITHOUT ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) in SQLite):

```
CREATE TABLE MySQLTable(
    name        VARCHAR(128),
    description VARCHAR(64),
    field       VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY(name, description)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE SQLiteTable(
    name        VARCHAR(128),  -- SQLite ignores the limits
    description VARCHAR(64),
    field       VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY(name, description)
) WITHOUT ROWID;
```

Comment: Thanks, will try MySQL technique, and post back with results.

Comment: Thank you, the following worked, To test, I've added a million records, upon inspection it was taking up 50% more space then I was expecting, but after an optimize call on the table, it shrunk to the size I was expecting.  
OPTIMIZE TABLE `test_db`.`MySQLTable` OK 0.000 sec